# How Math.Round is working?

Tags: c#

Recently I found an issue with C# [Math.Round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx) that makes me confused:

```
Math.Round(1.125, 2) == 1.12
```

However:

```
Math.Round(1.115, 2) == 1.12
```

Also

```
Math.Round(1.225, 2) == 1.23
```

And

```
Math.Round(1.215, 2) == 1.22
```

The last three samples are make sense just want to know how does it work for the first one?

Regarding to the document, if round to nearest even number then why in third sample round to Odd number?

Is anyone has any idea how is rounding the digits?

**Updating**

As I put the link, I know try to round to nearest even number, I want to know how implementing it (Using shift bytes)?

Comment: I think documentation is clear. Have you ever read it completely? Which part do you stuck exactly?

Comment: Scroll down in the documentation that you linked to in the remarks section ... "Rounds a decimal value to the nearest integer, and rounds midpoint values to the nearest even number"

Comment: I want to know how does it work in back end? why round to nearest even number

Comment: @Peyman - Again, scroll down in the documentation. "Rounding to nearest is the standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical operations.It conforms to IEEE Standard 754, section 4. When used in multiple rounding operations, it reduces the rounding error that is caused by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction. In some cases, this rounding error can be significant."

Comment: It does [Banker's Rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) by default, and mathematical rounding optionally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is trivially answerable by **reading the documentation.**

Comment: @Sayse of course I read that document, that's why I mentioned in my question, but it's not working in all cases that's why I get stuck, and I guess something like David's answer and just wan't to make sure. But can not see any reason for down voting

Comment: @Peyman - At no point during your question do you mention anything about what you may have read in the documentation (before your update) - without which is it unclear exactly what you are asking about and since it was so easily found in the documentation, it doesn't really show research effort

Comment: @Sayse, as I already mentioned I read it before raised the question, but couldn't find the answer there. Just mentioned floats are storing as binary, but didn't mention use what algorithm to round binary data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last three examples, it's working as documented. In the first case though, it appears to go wrong:

```
Math.Round(1.125, 2) == 1.12 // Would expect 1.13
```

The reason is simple: floats are stored as binary values; not decimal. So it's rounding the binary value that 1.125 has been converted to. In this case it is slightly below 1.125 and thus rounds "the wrong way".